# Need to exclude a column in a loop

Tags: excel, vba

This code works great for what I need it to do but it stops at column BC.  I need it to continue through the row but exclude the cell in that row that falls in column BD.  It is searching for any info in that row but column BD always has generic info so it always gets a false positive because of that column.

I have tried various loops and if statements to exclude the column BD but it always blows up on me.

```
    For Each Cell In Range("E2:E" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
       Dim rng4 As Range

       Set rng4 = Range("E" & Cell.Row & ":" & "BC" & Cell.Row)   'AE

        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng4) = 0 Then
           Range("D" & Cell.Row).Value = "IDINO"

        Else
            Range("D" & Cell.Row).Value = "IDI"
        End If


    Next Cell
```

Everything I have tried either does not change the current results or gives me all IDINO in the column or all IDI in the column.  Getting frustrated if anyone can steer me in the right direction I would be grateful.

Comment: `Set rng4 = Range("E" & Cell.Row & ":" & "BC" & Cell.Row)   'AE`To --> `Set rng4 = Union(Range("E" & Cell.Row & ":" & "BC" & Cell.Row) , Range("BE" & Cell.Row & ":" & "XX" & Cell.Row))  'AE`

Comment: `Set rng4 = Cell.EntireRow.Range("E1:BC1,BE1:ZZ1")`  The row number here is relative to `EntireRow`

Comment: This work perfect thanks